# Which version of Windows do I have?

Tags: windows

I do not know which Windows version I have running on my laptop. How do I find this out? I need to know before telephoning my service provider.

Comment: Hit `Windows + Pause/Break` or run `system.cpl` to view information about your windows SKU (version) and licensing status.

Comment: `system.cpl` does not work in Windows 10. Instead you can visit this link, which gives you the steps to find out the OS for different Windows OS'es. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows/which-operating-system

Comment: don't you know how your desktop looks? Unless you install some GUI changer, it'll look different in each windows version

Comment: @FrankThomas: Why do you answer in the comments section?

Comment: @FrankThomas: I'd argue that answering a low-quality question (be that in the answer section as intended, or in the comments section) only encourages further low-quality questions. Furthermore, doing so in the comments section breaks the Q&A model — if your response is incorrect then there _should_ be a way to indicate that to others by downvoting it; posting something you think may be wrong as a comment just so people can't then downvote you to indicate that is dangerous! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @FrankThomas: Regardless, comments are for requesting clarification, and critiquing. Not answering. Please adhere to the model, for the benefit of us all. Thanks. You are quite correct that that list does not include conversation, so I shall stop now! :)

Answer (score 41):

Press `Win + R`, type `winver` and press `Enter`. You will see a dialog with your version of Windows that looks something like this:

[image]

Another way is to press `Win + Pause/Break` which will open `System` window that also has info on the version of your OS. It might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I believe both methods you mention work on all versions since XP. Nice!

Comment: Since I have a Win 2000 machine powered up next to me, I decided to run a little test too. Both methods work on Windows 2000 Pro SP4 as well.

Comment: `winver` works all the way back to Windows 3.1, and possibly even before that.

Comment: and `ver` works all the way back to the old DOS days.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for pause/break that usually works on laptops which lack that key?

Answer (score 10):

If, for some reason, you wanted to do this from a command line:

```
systeminfo | findstr /b /c:"OS Name"
```

(Reference: [Find Windows Version from CMD](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/).) It has the added bonus of showing the OS edition. For me, it produces the following:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
```

This works on all versions since XP. You can produce the command prompt with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by `cmd` in the resulting dialog, as mentioned a couple times by other answers.

All versions before XP, if I remember correctly, clearly show the OS version and edition when booting up.

Comment: You can also use this: `wmic os get Caption` which will also work remotely.

Comment: @Abraxas Neat! One caveat is that `wmic os` isn't a thing in XP, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 7):

If you will check your edition op your Windows pc, you can right click on start button and select system.

[image]

This opens a window where you can find your spec's *(specifications)* of your computer. You can also use this shortcut <kbd>Win icon</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

Comment by @BenN, works this for Windows 8 and newer *(this are: Windows 8, 8.1 and 10)*. For older OS, please check other answers.

Comment: The Windows button menu (Win+X menu) only appears on WIndows 8 and newer.

Comment: [+1 for freehand things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/310919) :D

Answer (score 6):

```
wmic os get Caption,CSDVersion
```

Along with the other answers you can run this in the commandline and get an output like:

```
c:\>wmic os get Caption,CSDVersion /value
Caption=Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
CSDVersion=Service Pack 1
```

CSDVersion may not return anything and isn't strictly needed but it can be useful if you want SP.

More detail [here.](http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/)

Comment: This is a good option.  `winver` just shows me Windows 8, only mentioning that it's actually 8.1 Pro in small text about the trademark.  This clearly shows `Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro`.

Comment: @flimbusakimbo Thanks! Feel free to edit out the csdversion if you don't think there is value in it,  I was 50/50 on it

Comment: Showing the service pack level is definitely useful, no worries there.

Comment: and as it is wmi native, its accessible remotely.

Answer (score 5):

Using a Run command  <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> opens the run box, then enter:

> control /name Microsoft.System

Hit the OK button.

[image]

This will show you the installed Windows version.
This Run command works in Vista, W7, W8, W8.1, w10

Comment: I think this even works in XP.

Comment: I cannot get it to work in XP, but "control sysdm.cpl" does.

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/control-panel-command-line.htm

Comment: `control sysdm.cpl` also works in Windows 2000.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the Windows command line
2. Normally the Windwos version is already just by opening the "cmd"

[image]

3. If not then you can see the version by using the command `ver`

[image]

4. Now you can see the Windwos version by number! Just look at the table below to get the version by name!

[image]

Comment: This does not provide detail about if it is 'home' 'enterprise' 'pro' etc. like some other answers here. It may be worth adding that in if possible.

Comment: Note : Buildnumber 9200 is still wrong, it is 9600 for 8.1 and 2012R2 as per comment [Why does the cmd show the Windows version number as being 6.1.7601?](http://superuser.com/posts/comments/1261417)

Comment: @Abraxas He just asked for the "version", not for the "edition"

Answer (score 4):

If you still can't find the version, you can use the keys:(windows) + (R) to open up a prompt.

[image]

Then Type: "dxdiag" (without "")
It should ask if you want to view drivers that are not signed. Click "Yes"

It should return this picture. There's also a LOT of other useful information in this tool. I've pointed out where you can find your OS info.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Up to Windows 7:

- click on windows icon (bottom left corner)
- right click on "computer" in the right column
- select "properties"

From Windows 8: see Luis's answer.

Comment: This does not work with Windows 10 (I suppose Windows 8 is also the same). From the start menu, you do not see "My Computer"

Comment: The icon's name bas been changed in versions after Windows 7 but this method does work on Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Click this link: [Microsoft - Which Operating System](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/which-operating-system)

By default, Windows reports it's version to the websites you visit.

Websites designed to take this info and report it back to you exist, like the one above.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you were ignorant, merely asked as you downvoted, and suggested I do something irrelevant without investigating the link or even reading the question so that you could judge my answer's context. Doing so, you have found that this is one of the side-cases where a brief answer containing a link, can fully answer the question. Perhaps you should pay more attention to the content of the post and not the potential reputation gain. I apologize for calling you ignorant, there was no need to for it.

Comment: Whatever, your comment was rude, mine was not (it was just not applicable to your answer).  A screenshot or further explanation like you NOW provided would have avoided my comment.

Comment: That link does not tell you whether your have home, pro, enterprise, etc.

Comment: The question was which windows version, not which windows edition.