# How can I see which version/release of Windows 10 is installed on my computer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My underpowered netbook which came with Windows 10 never managed to succeed in updating itself to the first major upgrade to Windows 10 at about the end of 2015. (My similarly underpowered Windows tablet had no problem with it.)

Now it seems to be installing updates quite often onto itself, so I'm always interested to see if it's managed to update to a newer Windows 10 or only installs the smaller patches, device driver updates, etc.

I thought I could see this info by clicking on the message that tells me "updates were installed", but now I don't see anything there.

I'm quite surprised that by using the "Search the web and Windows" or by Googling I can't find a straightforward way to see the OS version info. Even the System Information page only tells me "Windows 10". What very obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: The canonical question might be *[Easiest way to find out if user has either Windows 7 or Vista (through telephone support)?](http://superuser.com/questions/401370)* (currently 106 upvotes and 20 answers (highest 138 upvotes)). [Adam Thompson's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/401370/easiest-way-to-find-out-if-user-has-either-windows-7-or-vista-through-telephone/401390#401390) and [Oliver Salzburg's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/401370/easiest-way-to-find-out-if-user-has-either-windows-7-or-vista-through-telephone/401392#401392) have information about the finding the version.

Comment: cont' - That also applies to Windows 10 (?). There must be a rational that reason *[Which version of Windows do I have?](http://superuser.com/questions/1045778/which-version-of-windows-do-i-have)* is closed as a duplicate of *[Easiest way to find out if user has either Windows 7 or Vista (through telephone support)?](http://superuser.com/questions/401370)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the start menu, click the settings cog. Click on System, then About in the left column at the bottom.  [image]

Comment: Aha this was the specific place I was thinking of and then couldn't find when I needed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

1. Windows key + `R`
2. Type "winver"

I've known `winver` to be the standard "get version number" utility since XP IIRC

**Edit** some comments suggest that `winver` has been around since at least 3.0

Example output:

[image]

Comment: What is `IIRC`? winver.exe exists on my Windows NT 3.5 from 1994 and possibly in the very first NT 3.1 from 1993 as well.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf if i remember correctly

Comment: I knew it would be super obvious, thanks! Somehow I thought I had seen it in newer places in Windows but this is of course perfect (-:

Comment: `winver` was available at least from 3.0 Windows version.

Comment: Or open  Paint/Notepad/Wordpad and click About, and the same window will pop up.

Comment: winver has been around [since Windows 1.0](http://zdnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2015/07/23/db9b07b8-1bd3-4451-9365-7bd336f4d7dd/resize/1170x878/6a5511eafc6e9a454add33945466f8ed/cmwindows1-0jul15a.jpg).

Answer (score 6):

Click on Start => Run and type `winver` and hit enter or run a command line window and type `winver`and hit enter. It will give you a more detailed version number (including the build).

Another option would be to press Win+R to bring it up or the task manager which still should have a run option as well and run `winver` using that dialog. Alternatively just search for `winver` in the `C:\Windows` directory (using a file search, not manually) or check this [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/) article which also has some more solutions.

Comment: I don't know about you but I don't see the Run utility in the Win10 start menu any more.

Comment: Keep looking it's there

Comment: @adampski edited the answer to give some more options.

Answer (score 1):

And let's not forget about the command line version. Type, the following in the Search the web and Windows text box:

```
cmd /k ver
```

Comment: `cmd` alone gives version number also.

Comment: Or specifically, just `ver`. `cmd /k` starts a CMD session, runs `ver` and *does not close the session*. So if you were to use it on a batch file, you should just use `ver`.